# PHP - Problem with sorting my multidimensional array?

Tags: php, arrays, symfony, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array that looks like this:

[image]

```
array:3 [
  0 => array:2 [
    "titre" => "Un package test"
    "nbDDL" => "3"
  ]
  1 => array:2 [
    "titre" => "retest"
    "nbDDL" => "1"
  ]
  2 => array:2 [
    "titre" => "ytjrtj"
    "nbDDL" => "1"
  ]
]
```

I would like to sort it by `ASC` or `DESC` order (depending on a variable passed in function parameter) with the `nbDDL`.

I looked at the method `array_multisort()` but I can not put it in place.

I work under Symfony 3.
Currently, I have:

```
if($ordreTri == "ASC")
{
    $liste = array_multisort("nbDDL", ASC);
}
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Post code as text instead of text in images  so people can copy paste easily

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a few different ways of doing this - you can introduce your own custom sort by using `usort()` and the spaceship operator `<=>`, but you can use `array_multisort()`, you just have to combine it with `array_column()`.

You can sort the array by first fetching all the `nbDDL`s. Then use that as the sorting-array in `array_multisort()`, and sort by ascending order (`SORT_ASC`). Apply that to `$array`, and you're done!

```
// By reference, $array is changed
array_multisort(array_column($array, "nbDDL"), SORT_ASC, $array);
```

This is done by reference, so you don't need to assign it to a variable. The return-value of `array_multisort()` is a boolean, which means that if you assign it as

```
// By reference - $result is bool
$result = array_multisort(array_column($array, "nbDDL"), SORT_ASC, $array);
```

Then `$result` is either true or false, but not the sorted array.

- Live demo at https://3v4l.org/9JYe5
- [PHP.net on `array_multisort()`](https://php.net/array-multisort)

Comment: Wow, great, thanks for this help, and the explanations that go with it! Thank you so much !

Answer (score 1):

You can try like below:

```
$data = [
    ['a' => 'a', 'order' => 1],
    ['b' => 'b', 'order' => 3],
    ['c' => 'c', 'order' => 1]
];

array_multisort(array_column($data, 'order'), SORT_DESC, SORT_NUMERIC, $data);

print_r($data);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do as following way:

```
function array_sort($array, $on, $order=SORT_ASC){

    $new_array = array();
    $sortable_array = array();

    if (count($array) > 0) {
        foreach ($array as $k => $v) {
            if (is_array($v)) {
                foreach ($v as $k2 => $v2) {
                    if ($k2 == $on) {
                        $sortable_array[$k] = $v2;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                $sortable_array[$k] = $v;
            }
        }

        switch ($order) {
            case SORT_ASC:
                asort($sortable_array);
                break;
            case SORT_DESC:
                arsort($sortable_array);
                break;
        }

        foreach ($sortable_array as $k => $v) {
            $new_array[$k] = $array[$k];
        }
    }

    return $new_array;
}
```

Use function as like:

```
$list = array(
   array( 'type' => 'suite', 'name'=>'A-Name'),
   array( 'type' => 'suite', 'name'=>'C-Name'),
   array( 'type' => 'suite', 'name'=>'B-Name')
 );

$list = array_sort($list, 'name', SORT_ASC);
```

Answer (score 0):

normally, you can use array_multisort to sort the array, but somehow it's weird thatin php7.4 it returns boolean (true or false) instead of sorted array like in php 5. I mean, a sorted array is what we actually need, not the boolean values.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33328908)